# Tokens and postfix expressions

Tags: java, switch-statement, token, postfix-mta

I am currently working on a homework building a calculator that can evaluate string expressions in postfix format. I have added to my code the ability to evaluate ^*/+- but now I need to add to it the ability of performing sin, cos, and tan functions using tokens and switch cases. I have started by adding a switch for sine, however the problem that I am running into is that I always get a numberFormatString exception for "n", which makes sense since that would be the last value in the expression. What I have noticed is that my code disregards the switch for "sin" and goes to whatever the default is.

```
public class Postfix {

    /**
     * Private constructor
     */
    private Postfix() {
        // empty constructor
    }

    /**
     * Evaluates the expression in postfix
     * @param expression
     * @return
     */
    public static double eval(String expression) {
        ArrayDeque<String> operandstack = new ArrayDeque<>();
        StringTokenizer postfixParser = new StringTokenizer(expression, "^*/+-|sin| ", true);

        /**
         * Checks if the token has more tokens
         */
        while (postfixParser.hasMoreTokens()) {
            String token = postfixParser.nextToken().trim();

            if (token.length() > 0) {
                System.out.println(token);
                double operand1 = 0.0;
                double operand2 = 0.0;
                double result = 0.0;

                /**
                 * Evaluates each token
                 */
                switch (token) {
                    /**
                     * Finds the sine value of the operand
                     */
                    case "sin":
                        operand1 = Double.valueOf(operandstack.pop());
                        result = Math.sin(operand1);

                        operandstack.push(String.valueOf(result));
                        break;
                    /**
                     * Creates exponential formula and pushes the result to the stack
                     */
                    case "^":
                        operand1 = Double.valueOf(operandstack.pop());
                        operand2 = Double.valueOf(operandstack.pop());

                        result = Math.pow(operand1, operand2);
                        operandstack.push(String.valueOf(result));
                        break;

                    /**
                     * Creates a multiplication formula and pushes the result to the stack
                     */
                    case "*":
                        operand1 = Double.valueOf(operandstack.pop());
                        operand2 = Double.valueOf(operandstack.pop());

                        result = operand1 * operand2;
                        operandstack.push(String.valueOf(result));
                        break;

                    /**
                     * Creates a division formula and pushes the result to the stack
                     */
                    case "/":
                        operand1 = Double.valueOf(operandstack.pop());
                        operand2 = Double.valueOf(operandstack.pop());

                        result = operand1 / operand2;
                        operandstack.push(String.valueOf(result));
                        break;

                    /**
                     * Creates an addition formula and pushes the result to the stack
                     */
                    case "+":
                        operand1 = Double.valueOf(operandstack.pop());
                        operand2 = Double.valueOf(operandstack.pop());

                        result = operand1 + operand2;
                        operandstack.push(String.valueOf(result));
                        break;

                    /**
                     * Creates a subtraction formula and pushes the result to the stack
                     */
                    case "-":
                        operand1 = Double.valueOf(operandstack.pop());
                        operand2 = Double.valueOf(operandstack.pop());

                        /**
                         * Checks if the operand1 is greater than operand 2, if so subtracts operand1 from operand2
                         */
                        if (operand1 > operand2) {
                            result = operand1 - operand2;
                            operandstack.push(String.valueOf(result));

                            /**
                             * Else subtracts operand2 from operand1
                             */
                        } else {
                            result = operand2 - operand1;
                            operandstack.push(String.valueOf(result));

                        }

                        break;

                    /**
                     *  If no operators, pushes the token to the stack
                     */
                    default:
                        operandstack.push(token);
                        break;

                }

            } else if (token.contains("sin")) {
                double operand1 = Double.valueOf(operandstack.pop());
                double result = Math.sin(operand1);

                operandstack.push(String.valueOf(result));
            }

        }

        /**
         * returns the value from the stack as a double
         */
        return Double.valueOf(operandstack.pop());
    }
}
```

My test code is below:

```
double result = Postfix.eval("5.0 sin");
        assertEquals(0.87, result, 0.1);
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of comments about your code.

First, your bottom else block is useless and can be eliminated, it will never evaluate, since token.length will be 0, and then the string certainly cannot contain "sin". Adopt an IntelliJ as an IDE that would catch such mistakes immediately via static analysis.

Your problem is in your tokenizer. Basically you need to tokenize differently, on spaces -- `" "`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to correct my code by removing the "sin" from the delimeters and also converting the result to radians.